# How to restore db dump using psycopg2

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-14.04, psycopg2, psql

Am taking backup of postgres database using pg_dump command using linux command line.
Want to retsore databse using psycopg2. Running following command

```
cur.execute(open("db.sql", "r").read())
```

It's throwing error:

```
syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1890: \.
```

Comment: What are the contents of line 1890 in the sql file? Maybe it's an psql backslash command which isn't supported by psycopg2?

Answer (score -4):

If you make the dump in command line, why don't you use it again to restore?

In command line:
psql dbname < dumpfile

If you need to do it in a python script, you can use "subprocess" and fire the same command.